# pyimage# does not exist: only after an error occurs, I get this error

Tags: python, tkinter

If I run my code in a newly created console (using spyder), and no error has occurred on any previous run, the code works fine.  But if I run it, and ANY error occurs, the next time I run it, I get

"TclError: image "pyimage5" doesn't exist"

I can close the console, and open a new one as work around, but this is getting real annoying real quick.  I am fairly new to tkinter, and this is driving me nuts! please help.

My code is below:
(to be clear, this is just a piece of the code)

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
# import tkinter
import customtkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("green")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

# PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
PATH = os.path.dirname(r'C:\Users\zwaldman\.spyder-py3\test_images\bg_gradient.jpg')

class App(customtkinter.CTk):

    APP_NAME = "VXL Labeling Wizard"
    WIDTH = 900
    HEIGHT = 600

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.title(App.APP_NAME)
        self.geometry(f"{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}")
        self.minsize(App.WIDTH, App.HEIGHT)
        self.maxsize(App.WIDTH, App.HEIGHT)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        
        # load image with PIL and convert to PhotoImage
        self.image1 = Image.open(PATH + "/bg_gradient.jpg").resize((self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT))
        self.bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image1)

        self.image_label = tk.Label(master=self, image=self.bg_image)
        self.image_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

        # self.image1= x
    
    def on_closing(self, event=0):
        self.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

EDIT: Corrected: console, not terminal.

Comment: What is the *terminal* actually? IPython or IDLE? If there is error, the instance of `CTk()` may still exist which cause the exception in next run.

Comment: so I'm using spyder. I think I meant console, not terminal. Will edit.

Comment: Spyder is using IPython console, so may have the issue said in my last comment.

Comment: If there is I don't see it or know what it is called. How would I find/fix it?

Comment: The exception is due to multiple instances of `Tk()` which is what `CTk()` inherits from.  Your code works fine basically in normal situation.